# Wordpress, How to customize the Description line of the Original Biographical Info field

Tags: php, wordpress, author

I googled it before asking without any success, I'm trying to change or customize the description line under Biographical info box in the author profile admin, I just wanna add " (Limited to 200 characters) " to the description line. any help please, Thanks! 
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k3sM.jpg)

OR adding error msg with the limited characters?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > in general or reading tab you can change the description text